# Finetuning Mistral or MistralForSequenceClassification for text classification

Tags: natural-language-processing, training, python, large-language-models, fine-tuning

I need to do text classification and have a dataset of 10K entries. I am considering using mistral and following a tutorial like https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training and replace model name by Mistral. But I have noticed there is also MistralForSequenceClassification.

Could you please help me with the following questions:

Is using the above mentioned tutorial and replacing the model name with mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1 the correct approach?

Do I need to use MistralForSequenceClassification?

Many thanks.